# Wordpress 3.4 upgrade creating jQuery issues

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have upgraded my site to wordpress 3.4 and its breaking nearly all the plugins that uses jQuery. I think the reason is its loading the wp-includes/jquery file after wp-head.

Please let me know any solutions for this..

Thanks and regards

Comment: You need to give us more clues. Are there JavaScript errors? Can you link us to the site?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with WordPress 3.4 as it works perfectly in many sites including mine. You should check your theme in how your theme handles the jquery. WordPress 3.4 load the scripts on `wp_head` alright ...

Comment: Hello guys...
have a look at this page.
jquery is defined after header by wordpress.
This is the thing creating issues and I was asking for the same..
http://rjmultimedia.in/beckysfund/

Only one of the thing is working properly, either the frontend or the dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the ff. on your template folder (wp-content/templates/template-folder/functions.php)

```
add_action('wp_head', 'load_scripts'); // to load jquery on the font page
add_action('admin_head', 'load_scripts'); // to load jquery on the admin page
function load_scripts(){
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
//insert all other wp_enqueue_scripts() calls here
}
```

Details at [webdev-tuts/wordpress/jquery-is-not-defined-in-wordpress-3-4.html](http://www.webdev-tuts.com/wordpress/jquery-is-not-defined-in-wordpress-3-4.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('wp_head', 'load_scripts'); // to load jquery on the font page
add_action('admin_head', 'load_scripts'); // to load jquery on the admin page
function load_scripts(){
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
//other scripts
}
```

Also, if you know the plugins,you can enqueue 'jquery' explicitly in the list of scripts.

Comment: Hello guys...
have a look at this page.
jquery is defined after header by wordpress.
This is the thing creating issues and I was asking for the same..
http://rjmultimedia.in/beckysfund/

Only one of the thing is working properly, either the frontend or the dashboard.

Comment: I did used your solution. Its fine for me in the frontend now but the dashboard is not working..

Answer (score 0):

It appears WordPress is now loading all scripts in the footer - place your scripts there and it will work ok

Answer (score 0):

Subharanjan's answer was correct for me -- as was WebandSteak's.

I have a custom modal pop up that I use on a couple of my e-commerce sites and I found that I needed to call jQuery using Subharanjan's method of forcing jQuery to enqueue in the header but then I needed to not call my jQuery functions until after the wp_footer() function call in footer.php.

I have a full write up to my solution here if you need a better explanation -- https://bitly.com/O6pBUN